# Clustering on time period in panel data

Tags: cluster-analysis, stata, panel-data

I have panel data for 33 countries at a semiannual frequency from 1985 - 2010. I would like to estimate the effect of the age structure on the fiscal multiplier in STATA. To do this, I run a smooth-transition local projection to construct the impulse response functions. First, I generate the 3 smooth-transition variables for the log-transformed gdp, government spending and forecast error in government spending using the code:

```
foreach x in lrgdp lrg fe_ptdd {
gen z_`x' = yng*`x'
gen resz_`x' = (1-yng)*`x'
}
```

Then, I regress using the code:

```
forv h=0/10 {
xtreg lrgdp`h' l(1).z_lrgdp l(1).resz_lrgdp l(1).z_lrg l(1).resz_lrg z_fe_ptdd resz_fe_ptdd, fe vce(cluster t_id)
}
```

As it is likely that many fiscal shocks are somewhat global, it is plausible that the standard errors will be correlated across countries. Therefore, I want to cluster on time period. The code above works without clustering, but when i cluster on the time id, t_id, I get the error message: *panels not nested within clusters*. I get the same error if I try to cluster by the actual time variable (1985.5, 1986, 1986.5, etc.).

As I understand it, the same ID (in this case country) may not appear in more than one cluster (time period) - which I guess they do, as I have data for each country in all time periods. But I can't simply delete the time-dimension. If I try to cluster on country instead, the code works fine. How do I fix this and cluster on time periods?

Answer (score 1):

In general, with panel regressions, you would cluster at a level where you expect the *errors* to be correlated at. Typical empirical applications are to cluster at the level of treatment assignment in RCTs. In your case, if you assume that global shocks play a role, then I would include `i.t_id` as a covariate in the regression command.
That being said, there is an `xtreg` suboption, `nonest` to override this default behavior. You code would look like this then:

```
forv h=0/10 {
xtreg lrgdp`h' l(1).z_lrgdp l(1).resz_lrgdp l(1).z_lrg ///
               l(1).resz_lrg z_fe_ptdd resz_fe_ptdd,   ///
               fe nonest vce(cluster t_id)
}
```